# Catan and Seafarers 5-6 player expansion

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

I have both standard Catan and Catan Seafarer, thinking about buying the player extension to expand both games to 5-6 players. If I only buy the Seafarer's player extension, can I also use it onto my standard Catan to play with 5-6 players? Or do I have to buy the 5-6 player extension for each game?

Answer (score 14):

You need both player extensions in order to play with 5-6 players on Seafarers.  The Seafarers 5-6 player extension doesn't contain the pieces needed for the extra players.  You'll need the frame pieces, extra titles, houses, roads and cities from the regular Catan 5-6 player extension in order to play Seafarers with 5-6 people.

Comment: [sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Settlers_of_Catan_games#Expansions_and_extensions)